# How can we give arguments to the token-pasting operator parameter specified in the Macro function?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use systemd's helper macros, but I don't quite understand the working mechanism. Systemd macros as below;

```
#define DEFINE_TRIVIAL_CLEANUP_FUNC(type, func)                 \
        static inline void func##p(type *p) {                   \
                if (*p)                                         \
                        *p = func(*p);                          \
        }
```

I did not understand how to give the "p" parameter as an argument in the macro I mentioned above. I would like to explain the problem with an example.

First of all, I created udev enumerate object;

```
struct udev_enumerate* enumerate = udev_enumerate_new(pudev);
```

When I want to delete this object later, how do I do it using the systemd macro?

```
DEFINE_TRIVIAL_CLEANUP_FUNC(struct udev_enumerate*, udev_enumerate_unref);
```

Type and function are specified according to the macro, but how is the "p" parameter in the macro (ie the object that I produced) specified in the macro?

Comment: The `p` after `##` looks like an error to me. Could you give a link to the source?

Comment: You can take a look at this link : https://github.com/openSUSE/systemd/blob/d874a13efc51fe49c8870542fa1c9a64ca7e5e93/src/basic/macro.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"p" is not a parameter. It's just a text "p". I guess it is intended to stay for word "pointer". I found the mentioned line at [link](https://github.com/lastpass/lastpass-cli/blob/master/util.h#L27). It looks that the macro is used to create a wrapper for a given cleanup functions that checks if the given *pointer is not `NULL`* and *set the pointer to a cleaned object to the empty sentinel*. I can guess that the trailing "p" is the naming convention used in this project. After a few cleanup functions created with this macro there are some others like `freep()` and `unmaskp()`.

For example `DEFINE_TRIVIAL_CLEANUP_FUNC(int, myclean)` expands as:

```
static inline void mycleanp(int *p) {
    if (*p)
        *p = myclean(*p);
}
```

Assuming that the `udev_enumerate_unref()` is declared as:

```
struct udev_enumerate *udev_enumerate_unref(struct udev_enumerate *udev_enumerate);
```

the wrapped can be created with:

```
DEFINE_TRIVIAL_CLEANUP_FUNC(struct udev_enumerate *, udev_enumerate_unref)
```

And used as:

```
struct udev_enumerate* enumerate = udev_enumerate_new(pudev);

... do stuff with `enumerate`

udev_enumerate_unrefp(&enumerate);
```

Comment: As a result, given my situation, how can I use the "enumerate" object with this macro? Do I have to write a static inline function?

Comment: @Purgoufr, how `udev_enumerate_unref()` is declared?

Comment: Normally the usage of the function is "udev_enumerate_unref(enumerate);" and function decleration is "struct udev_enumerate *udev_enumerate_unref(struct udev_enumerate *udev_enumerate);"

Comment: @Purgoufr, what is the return type? `void`?

Comment: @tstanisi return type is "struct udev_enumerate *"

Comment: @Purgoufr, see the updated answer